# Symfony2 Google Books API

Tags: php, api, symfony, google-books

I have an issue getting a book from the Google Books API in Symfony2

I am posting this form for a page (/google)...

```
    <form action="/googlevolume" method="post"> 
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="40" value=""> 
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

and this is my controller for the result page (/googlevolume)...

```
public function googlevolume(Request $request)
{

        $enquiry = new Enquiry();

        $form->bind($request);

        $response = $enquiry->get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=".$form->get('title')->getData());

        $data=$response->json();

        $response2=$data['items'];

        return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:googlevolume.html.twig', array('items' => $response2));


}
```

I have tried posting this number from the form

```
1781100489
```

Which is the same as going to:
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=1781100489

However, when i put that number in the form and press search, i get this error

```
Controller "Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller\PageController::googlevolumeAction" for URI "/googlevolume" is not callable.
```

this is from my routing file...

```
google:
    pattern: /google
    defaults: { _controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Page:google }
    requirements:
         _method: GET

googlevolume:
    pattern: /googlevolume
    defaults: { _controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Page:googlevolume }
    requirements:
        _method: POST
```

this is googlevolume.html.twig ...

```
 {# src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Page/googlevolume.html.twig #}
 {% extends 'BloggerBlogBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
 {% block title %} Google Books{% endblock%}
 {% block body %}
 <header>
    <h1>Google Book</h1>
 </header>
 <br>
 {% for item in items %}
 <article>
 <img src="{{ item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}}"/>
 <h4>{{ item.volumeInfo.title}}</h4>
 {% if item.volumeInfo.description is defined %}
 {{ item.volumeInfo.description }}
 {% endif %}
 <strong> {{ item.volumeInfo.publishedDate }}</strong><br/>
 <b>{{ item.volumeInfo.authors | join }}</b>
 </article>
 {% endblock %}
```

Anyone got any ideas where i'm going wrong with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to serialize the request object when really you just want the value from the form. Try changing your request to the api to:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

...

public function googlevolumeAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null,[
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ])
        ->add('title','text')
        ->add('Search', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->bind($request);
    if($form->isValid()){
        $enquiry = new Enquiry();
        $response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=".$form->get('title')->getData()),true);

        if(array_key_exists('items',$response)){
            return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:googlevolume.html.twig', [
                'items' => $response['items']
            ]);
        } else {
            return new Response('Google Volume did not have any items', 400);
        }
    }

    return new Response('Google Volume Not Found', 404);
}
```

Then the route:

```
googlevolume:
    pattern: /googlevolume
    defaults: { _controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Page:googlevolumeAction }
    requirements:
        _method: POST
```

Then clear the cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

or just for dev

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: Do i need to change any other parts of the code? As i changed it to the first one and i still get the controller error

Comment: Thank you, Thats fixed it to a degree... however, now i get... Class Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller\Request does not exist

Comment: when i put the number 1781100489 in i get 'Google Volume Not Found'. iv added googlevolume.html.twig to the question

Comment: That means your form has errors. for debugging try changing the last line to `return new Response('Google Volume Not Found: '.$form->getErrors(true), 404);`

Comment: The CSRF token is invalid

Comment: try disabling the csrf_protection for the form, see the updated answer

Comment: Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry".
Did you mean to call e.g. "getBody", "getEmail", "getName" or "getSubject"?

Comment: I had assumed that `Enquiry` was some form of http service. Entities generally can not make get requests, how did you plan to get that information from google?

Comment: i was gonner use Guzzle